# Problem with ImageField and Admin Panel

Tags: django, django-admin

I know, this topic was there many time, but there is no clear answer:

invalid literal for int() with base 10

I use django. I just want to see pictures, which I've uploaded, by admin panel. In my model it's just ImageField. Nothing sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

What is the URL that the image links point to? That should give you a good idea about what is causing the problem.

Make sure to set your `MEDIA_URL` and that it has  a trailing `/`

I'm guessing the the admin is pointing to a relative url. Say... `/admin/myapp/mymodel/3/images/my-image.png`

It's a common error with the django admin because the admin site is expecting a primary key.